# ASP Security Exception: Same but different

Tags: asp.net

Raking my brain and I have tried many of the "solutions" found online. Basically we are demoing this application from a vendor and the initial install worked fine. The application is actually four different applications. On our Windows server we have our main site, with four applications inside of it for the vendor. All of these were using the default application pool. Everything was working.

They asked us to updated the software and things went to hell. Updating involved deleting all the old files and replacing them with the new ones they sent us and then updating our SQL database. We we finished two of the applications had the error:

```
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

I have found many answers regarding this. Change the Load User Profile to ture, tried that, Unblock all the dll files, tried that. Mess with the trust level, tried that. I have since separated the applications into their own pools (at the advice of the vendor but they seem to have no clue) and after messing with it a ton, I now have three of the applications running, oddly enough one of the ones initially running is the one that is not running. The thing is the application was running initially, all we did was updated the files to newer versions.

My question I guess is where is the System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission called? Is that just a general level Asp application thing? I am pulling out my hair about this and we might just have to tell the vendor to take their product elsewhere if we can't get it running, but I am 99% sure it's a server setup issue. Thing is, I've never dealt with software where the update process is, delete all your files and replace them with the ones in this zip file.

Any thoughts on this. I feel like I have tried most of the obvious solutions but need some deeper thoughts.

Comment: Assumed already read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.aspnethostingpermission.aspx) - it has to do with how ASP.Net applications are run in hosted environments. Do you have full control of the server? Have you tried running the apps in your local/dev box? It could be that the updates included calls that go beyond/violate the `Trust Level` in your (hosted) server - hence the attempt to try and run in local/dev - in local/dev, ASP.net runs in `Full Trust`. If things run without a hitch in local/dev/full trust, then this hopefully identifies a place to start...hth

Comment: Addendum (ran out of chars) - just for clarity, in hosted environments, ASP.Net is usually set to `Medium Trust` - so even things like SMTP are affected (e.g. restricted to Port 25, no other port can be used). You cannot "override" Trust setting in your Web App web.config (box will use machine level config).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up most likely being cause by the third party's application. Their instructions on installation did NOT state to have a separate application pool for each application. (There were essentially 4 parts. Once we switch to each application running on its own application pool, the problem went away.